# How Can i pass js value to sql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
function muIo($val){
    var val = $val;

    <?php $result = mysql_query("UPDATE category SET category_active=1 WHERE category_id=" +  val + "");?>

}
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` function library, it is deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` and query parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: thank you about your advice, i will work on it

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a POST request to the server where PHP will then grab that value.

PHP and MySQL are server side while JS is client side.

Check these questions out:
[send data to MySQL with AJAX + jQuery + PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392036/send-data-to-mysql-with-ajax-jquery-php)

[Javascript function post and call php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834138/javascript-function-post-and-call-php-script)

Comment: sorry i didn't get it. can you send me some exmple?

Answer (score 0):

`Javascript` is client side. In order to run `PHP` and execute `SQL Queries` you need to have this code on your server setup.

Once you have this server script set up, in order to `pass` javascript values to this script you need to send a `POST` or `GET` request to `PHP`.

A simple way to do this for a beginner would probably be to use `JQuery` to use their simple `POST` functionality.

See [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)